# python QT, pysde2 how to pass correctly json values to QLabel

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

Would like to know best approach how to handle QLabel and other component update on json data refresh (capturing data from my heat pump).

```
def queryHeatpump(self):
    url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/json"
    res = requests.get(url)
    msg = res.json()
    #print(res.text)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        hzPower = msg["heatpump"][8]["Value"]
        temperature = msg["heatpump"][9]["Value"]
        ....
        ....
        ....

    else:

        print("Query fail, please try again later!")
```

For Json refresh use QTimer:

```
 self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(lambda: Functions.queryHeatpump(self)) 
        self.timer.setInterval(6000)  # 1000ms = 1s
        self.timer.start()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. json contains data using the basic python types, if you need to show a numeric value in a label, use `setText(str(value))` (or use string formatting), if it's a numeric widget (like QSpinBox) and you get a number, use `setValue(value)`. Can you clarify what is your problem? Also note that `requests.get` is blocking, and it should not be used in the main thread as it would freeze the UI until it returns; consider using a QThread with appropriate custom signals (do **not** update the widgets from the thread!) or the QNetworkAccessManager from the QtNetwork module.

Comment: @musicamante I need proper logic how to update values, if anybody showed some code snipet with some comments  for  Qthread and custom signal implementation would be great !!! Iam still new with python.

Comment: About QThread, you have to do some research (there are various tutorials and there's plenty of related posts here in StackOverflow), we cannot answer about that here, as it would be off topic to the question. About your original question, there is no "proper logic", it's up to you, depending on the widgets you have and the data you are getting; right now your question is too broad, while we usually answer to specific and detailed questions. Please take your time to review the [tour] and also read [ask] and the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).